# Can you combine permissions?

Tags: python, django

I need to know if it is possible to combine two permissions in a django python project? My boss wants me to combine the clock_in and clock_out permissions into one called clock_in_out. I also would like to just make one permission to be able to encompass add, change, view, and delete a project instead of having separate ones to assign to admins.

I've tried adding in meta data to the model classes and adding @permission_required('manager.manage_project') before the applicable defs in the views.py file. I am new at python and so let me know if this is possible. I ran python3 manage.py makemigrations and migrate and it still didn't work how it should.

## models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):

   #uses EntryManager for querysets
   objects = EntryManager()
   no_join = models.Manager()

   class Meta:
       db_table = 'timepiece_entry'  # Using legacy table name
       ordering = ('-start_time',)
       verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
       permissions = (
           ('can_clock_in_out', 'Can use Pendulum to clock in and out'),
       )
```

## views.py

```
@permission_required('entries.can_clock_in_out')
@transaction.atomic
def clock_in(request):
    """For clocking the user into a project."""
    user = request.user
    # Lock the active entry for the duration of this transaction, to prevent
    # creating multiple active entries.
    active_entry = utils.get_active_entry(user, select_for_update=True)

    initial = dict([(k, v) for k, v in request.GET.items()])
    data = request.POST or None
    form = ClockInForm(data, initial=initial, user=user, active=active_entry)
    if form.is_valid():
        entry = form.save()
        message = 'You have clocked into {0}.'.format(
             entry.project)
        messages.info(request, message)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))

    return render(request, 'timepiece/entry/clock_in.html', {
        'form': form,
        'active': active_entry,
    })
```

I want to be able to just assign that user the can_clock_in_out and have it work.

Comment: It's possible, it's simply changing the permissions on the model just like you did and running `py manage.py makemigrations` and then `py manage.py migrate`. Were there any errors when you ran the commands?

Comment: No there were no errors when I ran that on terminal but when I assigned a test user that new permission and had them go to the page the page was blank.